# MySQL LOAD Data Performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL table

```
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`stn_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
`rec_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`pval` float NOT NULL,
`sig` float DEFAULT NULL,
`bval` float DEFAULT NULL,
`rmode` char(1) NOT NULL,
`rserver` char(2) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`data_flag` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The mysql 5.6.12 is just installed and has default config.
I tried insert data to the table using LOAD DATA.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'dt1500.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE my_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (stn_num,rec_time,pval,sig,bval,rmode,data_flag)
```

It took 55 sec to insert 1500 records. The table has 512000 records. I guess the time taken is too long, considering the fact that I may have much more records in live database and also I need to have a unique key and another index. I have removed these 2 for now, just to simplify the problem.
Please suggest how can I improve the performance of the MySQL. I have not done any change in MySQL configuration after the installation

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to disable indexes

   ```
   -- before import
   ALTER TABLE `my_data` DISABLE KEYS;

   -- after import
   ALTER TABLE `my_data` ENABLE KEYS;
   ```
2. You can also turn off some options:

   ```
   -- before import
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
   SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
   SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;

   -- after import
   SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
   COMMIT;
   ```
3. What kind of computer are you using? Is this virtual machine, some web server or home computer? 1500 records in 55 seconds is very slow, it should run faster even with indexes, autocommit and all checks. Maybe you have bad disk driver and disk works in PIO mode instead of DMA or something?